# href link to nowhere

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, href

I've got a hover effect under "Latest Playlists" 
https://phuzz.superhi.com/

but would like to make the link unclickable or not to go anywhere.
I've tried the return false and couple of other options but it just makes the page scroll to the top and reload?

This is what I've got at the moment:

```
  <a href="#"><em>2.</em><i> INTO THE FIRE BY SUCK</i> <img src="rs-13160-102513-black-flag-623-1382724540.jpg"> </a>
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you don't want it to be clickable, don't make it a link.

Comment: Provided you're doing it properly, `return false` should work. But you need to show us a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want it clickable, don't use `<a>` anchor in the first place.

Use `<span></span>` tag instead.

Comment: @BeatrizCóias glad it helped. Also  *(obviously feels kinda weird since it's my answer)* but it's a good practice to mark the answer you used (with the green checkmark), so the question is logged as solved. Also potentially upvote any other answers, that also worked / you found helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Please add below code in href=" ".

> href="javascript:void(0);"

This is work for me. Please try it.